# Moving image in pygame doesn't work

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to move an image with the keyboard arrows using pygame in MacOSX, but it doesn't work at all. All the code I find on the web says that my code is right, but it just doesn't do anything.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Game')

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)

FPS = 60
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

dead= False

player_img = pygame.image.load('images/player.png')

def player(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(player_img, (x,y))

squirtx =  (display_width * 0.45)
squirty = (display_height * 0.8)
pygame.key.set_repeat(10, 10)


while not dead:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                squirty -= 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                squirty += 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                squirtx += 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                squirtx -= 10
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    pygame.display.update()
    player(squirtx,squirty)


    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Any help I could get will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: No errors? Any traceback?

Comment: No errors, the image just stands still in the screen.

Comment: Btw, it'd be nice if you format the code in your post nicely. I'm sometimes confused with the code because of the improper indentations.

Comment: Its my first time posting here, sorry :) Will try to fix this.

Comment: What is the size of window you provided in the game?

Comment: The window is (800,600)

Comment: @JoãoPedroOliveira I have already edited the code can you rollback the edit

Comment: what is the background you are using? Is it any image or just a color?

Comment: The background is white. I defined it as an rgb set: `white = (255,255,255)`

Comment: It just started giving me this warning: `libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile` This might be the error?

Comment: @JoãoPedroOliveira no it is a warning not an error!

Comment: I suggest you try changing the image as because sometimes images acts weirdly when used in pygame library. Check if the problem still continues with another image

Comment: Just tried with 3 images, all with the same result :(

Comment: Please edit your question again and post an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy, paste and run without any changes. I've just added the missing variables and fixed the indentation and the code works correctly for me.

Comment: @skrx just edited with the example.

Comment: So, I ran it on Windows and it worked well, just didn't work on my Mac. Don't know why, though. Thanks anyways guys :)

Comment: Try to remove the first `pygame.display.update()` line. There should be only one `pygame.display.update()` call per frame. Actually, I can see the image moving with two update calls as well (in Windows), it only blinks sometimes, but maybe it works differently on your MacOSX computer.

Comment: If that doesn't fix the problem, then it could perhaps have to do with `pygame.key.set_repeat`. Does `pygame.key.get_repeat()` return `(10, 10)`?

Comment: Works fine for me on mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a trying a bunch of stuff, I figured out that the issue is that I was running the code with `python main.py`on the MacOS Terminal.

The problem is that it seems the window doesn't focus right when I run it this way.

To solve it, I just ran it using `pythonw main.py`

Thanks for all your help.